# Import .csv to Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, import

I try to load this .csv:

```
Time    Column01    Column02    Column03    
11.03.2004  09:17:02    236.81  237.31  236.45
11.03.2004  09:17:05    236.6   237.06  236.18
11.03.2004  09:17:08    236.67  237.16  236.28
11.03.2004  09:17:12    236.83  237.24  236.41
11.03.2004  09:17:15    233.84  234.2   233.4
...
```

using:

```
b=csvimport('u1.csv','columns',{'Time'});
c=csvimport('u1.csv','columns',{'Column03'});
```

first work, but second no. Anybody know why? I have this error:

Error using csvimport (line 200)
Cannot locate column header 'Column03' in the file 'u1.csv'. Column header names
are case sensitive.

Error in TSFP (line 4)
c=csvimport('u1.csv','columns',{'Column03'});

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23573-csvimport) is description about this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no commas in your file!

So strictly speaking, it's not a comma separated value file. From the looks of it, it's tab separated instead.

Probably you'll have better results using [dlmread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) as in the first example:

```
M = gallery('integerdata', 100, [5 8], 0); 
dlmwrite('myfile.txt', M, 'delimiter', '\t')
dlmread('myfile.txt')
ans =
    96    77    62    41     6    21     2    42
    24    46    80    94    36    20    75    85
    61     2    93    92    82    61    45    53
    49    83    74    42     1    28    94    21
    90    45    18    90    14    20    47    68
```

Comment: I tried this code, but I only got numbers, which didn't matched to original number:`96 77 62 41 6 21 2 42
24 46 80 94 36 20 75 85
61 2 93 92 82 61 45 53
49 83 74 42 1 28 94 21
90 45 18 90 14 20 47 68`

Comment: I'm sorry, I partly pasted the code in the example (corrected now). This writes a file, and then reads it back in, but of course you'd need to change the call to match your file name etc etc (read the docs for specifics).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `textscan` for this if you want to import all of the data. `dlmread` will only import numeric data, but your date and time columns need to be treated as strings.

```
filename='u1.csv';
fid=fopen(filename,'r');
C=textscan(fid, '%s%s%f%f%f', 'HeaderLines', 1);
fclose(fid);
```

`C` is a cell array, so to access the second value in the date column and the second value in Column01 you'd do this:

```
date = C{1}{2};
value = C{3}(2);
```

It's worth noting that this imports the date and time separately because there is whitespace between them in the file. If you wanted to recombine them you could do this:

```
C={strcat(C{1}, {' '}, C{2}), C{3:5}};
```